# datatable don't work with table loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table in a file called values.php, I call this file from index.php by ajax, in index I have the datatable scripts, the example tables that I write in the index work but the same table loaded via ajax doesn't work. whats is wrong?

Basic Project Code

```
function call_table() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "values.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
call_table();
```

PHP values.php

```
$data='
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="sorting-table" class="table mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order ID</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Ship Date</th>
                    <th><span style="width:100px;">Status</span></th>
                    <th>Order Total</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="text-primary">054-01-FR</span></td>
                    <td>Lori Baker</td>
                    <td>US</td>
                    <td>10/21/2017</td>
                    <td><span style="width:100px;"><span class="badge-text badge-text-small info">Paid</span></span></td>
                    <td>$139.45</td>
                    <td class="td-actions">
                        <a href="#"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="la la-close delete"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="text-primary">021-09-US</span></td>
                    <td>Jeffrey Arnold</td>
                    <td>US</td>
                    <td>07/21/2017</td>
                    <td><span style="width:100px;"><span class="badge-text badge-text-small info">Paid</span></span></td>
                    <td>$199.95</td>
                    <td class="td-actions">
                        <a href="#"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="la la-close delete"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';

echo $data;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working? The Ajax function looks fine and nothing in `values.php` looks peculiar under casual scrutiny.

Comment: So where & how are you initializing the DataTables functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only put the initializing code inside the ajax code after render the table

```
function call_table() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            $('#sorting-table').DataTable();        //here
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "values.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
call_table()
```

;